# Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: haskell, rock-paper-scissors

This is a very simple rock paper scissors game implemented in Haskell.

```
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import System.Random (getStdGen, randomR)

data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Ord RPS where
    Rock `compare` Scissors = GT
    Scissors `compare` Rock = LT

    Paper `compare` Rock    = GT
    Rock `compare` Paper    = LT

    Scissors `compare` Paper = GT
    Paper    `compare` Scissors = LT
    _ `compare` _ = EQ

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt text = do
    putStr text
    hFlush stdout
    getLine


main = do

    gen <- getStdGen

    humanchoice <- prompt "Rock, Paper, or Scissors: "

    let (compchoice, _) = randomR (0,2) gen
        compchoice' = case (compchoice :: Int) of
                          0 -> Rock
                          1 -> Paper
                          2 -> Scissors
        humanchoice' = read humanchoice :: RPS

    case compchoice' `compare` humanchoice' of
        EQ -> putStrLn "Tie."
        GT -> putStrLn "You Lose :("
        LT -> putStrLn "You Win! :)"
```

All kinds of reviews are welcome, but I am specifically interested in knowing what kind of beginner mistakes I might have done. For example, are there things that I could simplify, or are things that you wouldn't see in a intermediate level haskell code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @200_success mentions in a comment, this isn't a kosher use of `Ord`. I believe though that it is the property of antisymmetry that is broken, not transitivity. \$Rock \leq Paper \leq Scissors \leq Rock\$ means that by transitivity \$Paper \leq Rock\$, which violates antisymmetry since \$Rock \neq Paper\$. This may seem academic, but many library functions will break or produce incoherent results given your instance. Try to guess what `sort [Rock, Scissors, Paper]` will return. Don't get in the habit of writing bad instances just because you like their namespace.

What you should do instead is just write a grab bag of pure functions and domain-specific datatypes. This would look something like—

```
data Winner = PlayerOne | PlayerTwo | Tie

shoot :: RPS -> RPS -> Winner
shoot Rock Rock     = Tie
shoot Rock Paper    = PlayerTwo
shoot Rock Scissors = PlayerOne
-- ...
```

All top-level definitions should have a type signature always, full stop. `main` is always `main :: IO ()`.

Since you're not doing anything fancy with your `StdGen`, just use the `*IO` functions.

```
main = do
          humanchoice <- prompt "Rock, Paper, or Scissors: "

          compchoice <- randomRIO (0,2)
          -- ...
```

One typeclass it *would* be appropriate to instance is `Random`, so that you can have a more semantic computer-player interface. I'll toss in `Enum` and `Bounded` instances because they make the `Random` instance more future-proof.

```
data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Enum, Bounded)

instance Random RPS where
    random g = randomR (minBound, maxBound) g

    randomR (lo, hi) g = first toEnum $ randomR (fromEnum lo, fromEnum hi) g
        where first f (a, b) = (f a, b)
```

The last thing I would do would be to factor out the result message code from `main`, it's a little repetitive having `putStrLn` there three times, and you can conceive of various scenarios like making this two player where you'd want to be able to easily swap around result message generators.

```
humanTwo :: Winner -> String
humanTwo PlayerOne = "You lose :("
humanTwo PlayerTwo = "You win! :)"
humanTwo Tie       = "Tie."
```

And with all of those changes you end up with a `main` function like—

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
          humanchoice <- fmap read $ prompt "Rock, Paper or Scissors: "
          compchoice <- randomIO
          let winner = shoot compchoice humanchoice
          putStrLn $ humanTwo winner
```

Comment: I think `let (compchoice, _) = randomRIO (0,2) gen` should be `compchoice <- randomRIO (0,2)`. According to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.3/docs/System-Random.html randomRIO doesnt get a generator and doesnt return one

Comment: Any suggestions to improve the shoot function? It can get very large especially if we play Sheldon's variant: http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Rock_Paper_Scissors_Lizard_Spock

Comment: @yasar D'oh! You're completely right, I switched out `randomIO` for `randomRIO` without adjusting any of the context.

Comment: @GeneralBecos Interesting question. Provided an `Enum RPS` instance and a specifically ordered `RPS` definition, we can reduce the problem to modular arithmetic. E.g., `data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors | Lizard | Spock deriving Enum` `shoot left right | result == 0 = Tie; | odd result = PlayerOne; | even result = PlayerTwo; where result = mod ((fromEnum left + 1) - (fromEnum right + 1)) 5`.

Comment: You can use [`random-derive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-derive) to automatically create a `Random` instance defined in terms of `Enum` and `Bounded`.

Answer (score 5):

Just a footnote to the already excellent answer from bisserlis above. Started with a short discussion arising from the comments. I would implement the shoot function as below. It is simpler to understand (for me) + easier to extend to Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock

```
beats :: RPS -> RPS -> Bool
beats Paper    Rock     = True
beats Rock     Scissors = True
beats Scissors Paper    = True
beats _        _        = False

shoot :: RPS -> RPS -> Winner
shoot a b  
        | a == b      = Tie
        | a `beats` b = PlayerOne
        | otherwise   = PlayerTwo
```

Comment: Guard notation would be more idiomatic and tidier than `if-then-else if-then-else`.

Comment: Oh nice, that's very clever. I might even go so far as to define `beats` infix, e.g., `Paper \`beats\` Rock = True`.